# Prove $SO(3)$, the group of rotations of $\mathbb{R}^3$, is not homotopically equivalent to $S^1\times S^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Prove $SO(3)$, the group of rotations of $\mathbb{R}^3$, is not homotopically equivalent to $S^1\times S^2$.

I know that $\pi_1(SO(n))\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ and I think that $P:\mathbb{R}\times S^2 \to S^1 \times S^2 $ and $P(t,x)=(e^{2\pi it},x)$ is the universal covering space, and the fibre of the a element $x_0$ has more than two points, which can not be homotopically equivalents.

Comment: $\pi_1(S^1\times S^2)\cong\mathbb Z$.

Comment: $S^3$ is the universal covering space - see gimbal lock, quaternion rotations.

Answer (score 4):

If you know $ \pi_1(SO(n)) $, and $\pi_1(X \times Y ) $ = $ \pi_1(X) \times \pi_1(Y) $, and $ \pi_1 $ is a homotopy invariant, then you are done, no?

Comment: but in general π1(X×Y) = π1(X)×π1(Y) is not true.

Comment: Sure it is! ${}$